# Swift marcar o desmarcar checkbox

Tags: ios, swift2, swift

Tengo dos botones modificados para funcionar como un `checkbox` mediante una subclase (`@IBOutlet siCheckbox` y `noCheckbox`) si marco un `checkbox` el otro se desmarca automaticamente el problema es que por decir si presiono "si" una vez desmarca el "no" , pero si presiono el "si" de nuevo se desmarca a si mismo y marca el "no"

este es el codigo

```
import UIKit

class Paso1: UIViewController, CheckBoxDelegate   {


    @IBOutlet weak var siCheckBox: CheckBox!

    @IBOutlet weak var noCheckBox: CheckBox!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.siCheckBox.delegate = self
        self.noCheckBox.delegate = self}

    func checkBoxDidChange(checkbox: CheckBox) {
    if checkbox == self.siCheckBox {
        self.noCheckBox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked

    } else {
        self.siCheckBox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked

    }}
```

Y esta es la subclase que le tengo asignada a ambos botones

```
    protocol CheckBoxDelegate {
    func checkBoxDidChange(checkbox: CheckBox) -> Void }

   import UIKit

   class CheckBox: UIButton {

    // Images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "check-greenb")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "check-baseb")! as UIImage

    var delegate: CheckBoxDelegate?
    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        isChecked = !isChecked
        self.delegate?.checkBoxDidChange(self)
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta resuelto , a compartir

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if !isChecked {
        isChecked = !isChecked
        self.delegate?.checkBoxDidChange(self) 
}
}